# Evaluating `org-babel-clojure` blocks returns nill & result

Tags: org-mode, clojure, babel

Why the results is 'nil5'? Can't be just 5?

```
#+begin_src clojure :results
(+ 1 4)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: nil5
```

Also:

```
#+begin_src clojure
(print "Hello World!")
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: nilnil
```

I was expected just to print "Hello World!" in RESULTS.

Comment: `print` doesn't return the printed string, it returns `nil`. Where the second `nil` comes from, though, I have no idea.

Comment: In second case should be #+begin_src clojure :results output to return "contents of STDOUT". https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-evaluation.html 
But :results value should  output "value of last expression" but it eval everything in src_block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#+begin_src clojure :results pp
(+ 1 4)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 5
```

```
#+begin_src clojure :results output
(print "Hello World!")
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: Hello World!
```

So we have to specify the output.